# mvc4 checkbox update database

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, checkbox

I had taken an example from somewhere on the internet (I cant remember where it was) and have placed it into my application. The code works but not exactly to how I want it and I cannot seem to figure out how to complete it.

The code below takes all checked checkboxes and updates the database in the location it should. Great! However when you uncheck a checkbox there is no way of changing the field in the database from on to off.

I suspect I will have to do a complete code rewrite however here is what I have at present.

View:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.id)

                <td class="selectAll">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="complete" value="@item.id"/>

                </td>
            </tr>
         }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Complete(FormCollection c)
    {

        int i = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var DelIDArray = c.GetValues("item.id");
            var DelCompleteArray = c["complete"];

            for (i = 0; i < DelIDArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                string find = DelIDArray[i].ToString();
                deliverylist dels = db.deliverylists.Find(Convert.ToInt32(DelIDArray[i]));
                dels.is_complete = Convert.ToInt32(DelCompleteArray[i]);
                               }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Complete");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller code is only being fired when you submit the form.

You could use async methods (jquery) to call the update code when one of the checkboxes is clicked, but that would have it evaluate it for all checkboxes when you only really need to update one.

As you expected, there's a bit more work to do if you want it to work async.  Here is a bit of a primer on using mvc4/webapi/jquery together:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC-and-WebAP

Answer (score 0):

The code below gets me by and I can keep working however I know this cannot be right and I am looking for the proper solution.

The reason I have entered n with an increment of two is because the "complete" checkbox array collects both all false checkboxes and adds the true ones also throwing the alignment out. (if that makes sense)

This is my first attempt at updating a database with checkboxes

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.id)

            <td class="selectAll">
                 @if (item.is_complete == 1)
                 {
                   @Html.CheckBox("complete", true, new { id = item.id, @value = item.id })

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     @Html.CheckBox("complete", new { id = item.id, @value = item.id })

                   }
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Complete(FormCollection c)
{

    int i = 0;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var DelIDArray = c.GetValues("item.id");
        var DelCompleteArray = c["complete"];

        var n = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < DelIDArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            string find = DelIDArray[i].ToString();
             deliverylist dels = db.deliverylists.Find(Convert.ToInt32(DelIDArray[i]));
                if (c.GetValues("complete")[n] == "false")
                {
                    dels.is_complete = 0;
                    n = n + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    dels.is_complete = 1;
                    n = n + 2;
                }
                db.Entry(dels).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Complete");

}
```